# get_object_or_404 does not return object that I've verified to exist in database

Tags: python, django, ajax, postgresql

I've been trying to figure out why get_object_or_404 can't find an object that exists but I can't figure it out. So the problem is occuring when I try to call this function like this.

JS Ajax to call function:

```
  var url;
                url = {{ OrderItem.change_item_quantity}};
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            newquantity: realquantity
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                          console.log("success")
                          spinner{{ forloop.counter0 }}.addClass(pauseClass);
                          $("#totalprice{{ forloop.counter0 }}").css("display", "block")
                        },
                        error: function(errordata) {
                          console.log(errordata)
                        }
                    })



                changeTimer = false;

            },300);
```

This calls a function in my OrderItem model (models.py):

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(VarientItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity}x {self.item.item.title} of varient {self.item.varient} for {self.user.email}"

    def get_item_total(self):
        return (self.item.final_price * self.quantity)

    def change_item_quantity(self):
        return reverse("core:change_item_quantity", kwargs={
            'slug': self.item.item.slug,
            'ordervarient': self.item.varient,
            'orderfinalprice': self.item.final_price
        })

class VarientItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    varient = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.title
```

My url for change_item_quantity:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('change_item_quantity/<slug>/<ordervarient>/<orderfinalprice>', views.change_item_quantity, name='change_item_quantity')
]
```

Finally, my function actually lives in views.py:

```
def change_item_quantity(request, slug, ordervarient, orderfinalprice):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        new_quantity_str = request.GET.get('newquantity', None)
        new_quantity = ast.literal_eval(new_quantity_str)
        try:
            new_quantity_int = int(new_quantity)
            if int(new_quantity) <= 0:
                raise ValueError("Numbers can't be negative")
        except:
            response = HttpResponse('Quantity not Accepted', status=406)
            return response
        product = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
        varient_item = get_object_or_404(VarientItem, item=product, varient=ordervarient, final_price=orderfinalprice)
        order_item = get_object_or_404(OrderItem, item=varient_item, user=request.user, ordered=False)
        order_item.quantity = new_quantity
        order_item.save()
        response = HttpResponse({"new_quantity": new_quantity, "new_total": new_quantity*orderfinalprice, "items_in_cart": str(get_items_in_cart(request).content)}, status=200)
        return response
```

However, the problem is that once it gets to the variable varient_item, the get_object_or_404 returns a 404 error instead of finding the object. I've narrowed it down specifically to the varient variable that causes the issue. When I remove that it is able to find the object. However, looking at my models in the admin page and printing out what ordervarient equals, they are exactly the same (equal to each other). Printing order_varient would give me:

```
{'top': 'red', 'knob': 'black', 'bottom': 'white', 'middle': 'yellow'}
```

And looking at my admin page, VarientItem.varient has the value:

```
{"top": "red", "knob": "black", "bottom": "white", "middle": "yellow"}
```

Printing out the other fields yields the exact same values too. So clearly all the values are the same, so idk why get_object_or_404 isn't returning anything. I tried objects.filter too, but it also returned no object.

The database I'm using is postgres if that helps.

Comment: try manually finding the entity via `Item.objects.get(slug=slug)` and catching the `Item.DoesNotExist` exception in case it does not exist. Replace the model name for other bits.

Comment: I actually figured it out, for some reason it wasn't recognizing it was a dictionary so I evaluated it safel using this: ```varient=ast.literal_eval(ordervarient)```